# Api Connect - define a different security for each path

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have a node/express application that expose api using IBM ApiConnect on IBM Cloud.

**==UPDATE START==**

I'm not using IBM ApiConnect directly from a catalog service but I used option "Api Management" and updated an API Definition

**==UPDATE END==**

I need to define two kind of security api: **Open Api** and **Secured Api**.
The first one should be open and the second need Client Id and Client Secret.

I cannot define correctly this requirement, someone can help me?

**==UPDATE START==**

/callback/sign should be **open**

/services/products should be **secured**

**==UPDATE END==**

This is my yaml in sections:

Security Definition at Api Level

```
securityDefinitions:
  client_secret:
    type: apiKey
    description: ''
    in: header
    name: X-Client-Secret
  client_id:
    type: apiKey
    description: ''
    in: header
    name: X-Client-Id
security:
  - client_secret: []
    client_id: []
```

and finally the path definition:

```
paths:
  /callback/sign:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 OK
      security:
        - {}
    post:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 OK
      parameters:
        - name: body
          required: false
          in: body
          schema:
            type: object
      security:
        - {}
  /services/products:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the visual editor for that. Based on your example this is how your yaml file should look like:

```
  paths:
      /callback/sign:
        get:
          responses:
            '200':
              description: 200 OK
        post:
          responses:
            '200':
              description: 200 OK
          parameters:
            - name: body
              required: false
              in: body
              schema:
                type: object
      /services/products:
        get:
          responses:
            '200':
              description: 200 OK
          security:
            - client_id: []
              client_secret: []
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for you answer, but /callback/sign: should be open, in this way it require client_id and client_secret. Can you update your answer?

Comment: I don't understand, which operation should be unsecured? GET or POST?

Comment: [GET,POST] /callback/sign  -> unsecured  [GET] /services/products  secured. I'm thinking that if I add securityDefinitions section every path should be secured. Also with api security empty and defined for each path.

Comment: security definitions section only defines the available security options. They are not applied if you don't add it to the path or operation level

Comment: I think the same but in my condition it's no working. I'm not using directly api connect but I have activated under my nodejs application the "API Management" and imported the api definition but it's no working properly. Api Explorer describe correctly my definition but when I'm going to use it the behavior is this that I'm describing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a security default but then override it for one or more path/ops, "no security" / "open" should be coded as

`security: []`

rather than

`security:
  - {}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no effects. :(